# How to initialize Datatable in Angular 2+, without using JQuery

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

I have a table with a unique id. I want to initialize that as a datatable.
What syntax can be used for the same?

My table looks like:

```
<table id="myDataTable">
       <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Employee Id</th>
           <th>Employee Name</th>
           <th>Designation</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>123451</td>
            <td>Employee 1</td>
            <td>Senior Developer</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
           <td>123452</td>
           <td>Employee 2</td>
           <td>Developer</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

**In ts file I tried with below code:**

```
@ViewChild('myDataTable') myDataTable: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){
  this.myDataTable.nativeElement.dataTable({
    pagingType : 'full_numbers'
  });
}
```

This throws an error in browser console :

> "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

Could you please help, how do we achieve this without using `jquery($)` ?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` has nothing to do with it.

When you use `ViewChild`, your element will be initialized not in `OnInit`, but in the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle event.

Replace `ngOnInit` with `ngAfterViewInit` or add it.

```
@ViewChild('myDataTable') myDataTable: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit () {
  this.myDataTable.nativeElement.dataTable({
    pagingType : 'full_numbers'
  });
}
```

and your template must be with `template variable`. Angular detects your element via it.

```
<table id="myDataTable" #myDataTable>
```

Comment: I tried putting in the code for dataTable intialization in ngAfterViewInit(), but this also gives the same error.